# Detaching Connectivity Changes Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am using Xamarin.Essentials to handle connectivity changes, it all works on android

However I have noticed that in iOS it didnt work, I debugged and noticed that

1. sliding down the screen in iOS Physical device
2. Put the phone in Plane Mode and remove wifi
3. Sleep event fired and removed connectivity

   ```
   //App.Xaml

   protected override void OnSleep()
   {
       Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= OnConnectivityChanged;
   }

   protected override void OnStart()
   {
       Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += OnConnectivityChanged;
   }



   protected override void OnResume()
   {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += OnConnectivityChanged;
   }
   ```

if I comment out

```
 Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= OnConnectivityChanged;
```

it all works.
Am I missing the obvious?

WHere I am supposed to detach the connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Forms lifecycle is somewhat different from the declarative lifecycle approach of native platform, and you can do this directly in the native ios lifecycle.

in your ios project **AppDelegate.cs** :

```
public override void OnActivated(UIApplication application)
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

 public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged -= Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
    }

 private void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do some thing
    }
```

You could refer to the [lefecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo#walkthrough).

**Note**:
on iOS 13 (and later),you need write them to **SceneDelegate** as well.

Comment: hi thanks for the suggestion I will try that